# SwaggerUI not building - blank page in browser ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm have api app using ASP.NET Core. I'm also using swaggerUI and problem is when I start debugging application, browser open and just blank page appears. It should open swaggerUI but nothing happen. Using IIS Express. There's also no exception trown, any other error etc.
What can be a problem?

This is my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
      "sslPort": 44321
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[my project debug options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYSXl.jpg)
EDIT:
[this is how it looks in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QleJE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

SwaggerUI will not register as default start page. You need to browse `/swagger` manually.

If you want SwaggerUI to open automatically upon starting a debug session, go to you project settings -> debug -> "absolute or relative URL" textbox. Insert `swagger` there.

Comment: I don't have option "absolute or relative URL". I've got "Launch browswer" checbox checked and 'swagger' in textbox right to it.
I've added picture of my project debug options in main post.

Comment: Everything looks good on your screenshot. If you start debugging with F5, SwaggerUI should appear

Comment: I've added screenshot how it looks in browser

Comment: The URL taskbar doesn't show swagger it. What happens when you browse to `https://localhost:44321/swagger` ?

Comment: Nothing happens, it's same as the blank widnow. It just continue to loading but never actually do so.